# reverseGeocodeLocation returns placemark with some info in arabic and some in english

Tags: ios, localization, reverse-geocoding, mkplacemark

I have implemented `reverseGeocodeLocation` to get address from latitude and longitude. It's working fine.

I have change  language to arabic like this: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")`

Now, i'm calling  `reverseGeocodeLocation` function and getting result in arabic language.

But, for some latitude-longitude it's returns some info in arabic and some in english language. For example: 
Latitude: `21.1591493`
Longitude: `72.6823397`
City: `Surat`

Returns:
`placemark.name` = 394550
`placemark.locality` = Surat [English]
`placemark.administrativeArea` = غوجارات [Arabic]
`placemark.country` = الهند [Arabic]

So, Question is:
 why i am getting strange result for some locations?
What is workaround to get all info in arabic?

Note: I'm using Apple `CLGeocoder`'s reverseGeocodeLocation method, NOT Google api. So don't confuse.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer for 1 question.

It may be possible that google don't have the name english language that's why its returning in arabic.
 btw the default domain for the Geocoding Service is United States.

> Answer for 2 question.

You can also set the Geocoding Service to return results biased to a particular region explicitly using the region parameter. This parameter takes a region code, specified as a [IANA language region subtag](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry).

you need to pass region code parameter in request.
In your case it will region=ar.

for more info [go to documentation.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#reverse-geocoding-by-place-id)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am not using google for reverse geocode. I'm using apple's `CLGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation ` function for that.

Comment: no problem, i appreciate your effort to help others.